# Did anyone associated with Nobel Peace Prize comment later on Barack Obama being awarded one?

Tags: barack-obama, nobel-peace-prize

There are lots of random people (ironically, both left and right) who have issues with Barack Obama being awarded Nobel Peace Prize, although perhaps for different reasons. Of course, their opinions, whether more or less well reasoned, aren't very authoritative. But, *some specific people's opinions are more authoritative on the topic*.

Have anyone expressed themselves on the topic between 2012 and 2016 **who was involved with Nobel Peace Prize itself**, especially anyone who was actually involved with awarding Obama the prize in 2009 (ideally members of Norwegian Nobel Committee)? If so, were they expressing support for the decision or opposition, in light of the subsequent two Presidential terms?

Comment: There may be a kind of clause forbidding you to make comments later if you are part of a Nobel prize jury, and this for every field.

Comment: some of the committee that awarded it have spoken out, and obama himself considered not going to Oslo to accept, but i didnt see any other winners commenting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes, former director of the Nobel Institute, Geil Lundestad

Mr. Lundestad's memoir, *Secretary of Peace: 25 years with the Nobel Prize*, published in September 2015, revealed that the committee under his leadership awarded the Nobel Peace Prize to Barack Obama in order to aid him in future endeavors, rather than in recognition of past accomplishments.

> Geil Lundestad, director at the institute for 25 years, said in his just-published memoir that he and the committee had unanimously decided to grant the award to Mr. Obama just after his election in 2009 more in hopes of aiding the American president to achieve his goals on nuclear disarmament, rather than in recognition of what Mr. Obama had already accomplished.
>
> Looking back over Mr. Obama’s presidency, Mr. Lundestad said, granting him the award did not fulfill the committee’s expectations.
>
> “[We] thought it would strengthen Obama and it didn’t have this effect,” he told the Associated Press in an interview.
>
> <sub>–"[Nobel panel saw Obama peace prize as ‘mistake,’ new book claims](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2015/sep/16/nobel-panel-saw-obama-peace-prize-mistake-new-book/)", *The Washington Times*, 2015-09-16</sub>

Early reports, such as the one found in *The Washington Times*, emphasized this quote from his book:

> "Many of Obama's supporters believed it was a mistake," he writes. "As such, it did not achieve what the committee had hoped for."

However, Mr. Lundestad later called a press conference where he said in no uncertain terms that the Nobel Committee did not consider it a mistake.

> Following the media interest in Lundestad's memoir, the Norwegian historian called a press conference on Thursday to deny that he had implied that Obama didn't deserve the prize. "Several of you have written that I believe the prize to Obama a mistake, but then you can not have read the book," Lundestad told the assembled reporters, according to VG. "It says nowhere that it was a mistake to give Obama the Peace Prize."
>
> <sub>–"[Obama’s Nobel peace prize didn’t have the desired effect, former Nobel official reveals](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2015/09/17/obamas-nobel-peace-prize-didnt-have-the-desired-effect-former-nobel-official-reveals/?utm_term=.030e255f2233)", *The Washington Post*, 2015-09-17</sub>

Regardless, the rationale for awarding a Nobel Prize is usually kept private, and Mr. Lundestad revealing this in a frank way caused a political stir.